# return part of a string sql

Tags: select, path, directory

I have a column with a folder path structure

```
root01/folder01/sub-folder  
root01/folder2/subfolder  
root2/folder01/anothersub/evenmore  
root2/folder400/anothersub
```

Ideally I'd like a query that would return the 2nd to last folder, like

```
folder01  
folder2  
anothersub  
folder400
```

I'd also be happy with the path, up to the last level

```
root01/folder01  
root01/folder2  
etc...
```

Comment: Does it have to be a pure SQL solution? Or could you perform string manip on the results with whatever language you are processing the results with?

Comment: It does need to be purely sql. I'm not processing the results beyond the output I get from sql

Comment: So you're just entering queries and look at the results? You don't process the results for display?

Comment: right this second, yes. but once I get it right there, they'll be output as a csv

Comment: And how do you bring them into a CSV format? I'd do the string manipulation when putting the results into the CSV

Comment: The packaging to csv happens in the backend of third party software that I don't have access to.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
SELECT PARSENAME(REPLACE('root01/folder01/sub-folder', '/', '.'), 2)
```

as this solution works on sql server2005
for more information click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/how-do-i-split-a-string-so-i-can-access-item-x)